# Closed form for a double integral over the first quadrant of the $L^p$ disk

Tags: integration, special-functions

Is there, by any chance, a closed form for the following integral
$$
I_p=\iint_{Q_p}(x+y)\log(x+y)dxdy,
$$
where $Q_p=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x>0,y>0,x^p+y^p\leq1\}$, $0<p\leq\infty$ ?

Mathematica finds
$$
I_1=-1/9,\quad I_2=\frac{1}{9}\left(-8
-3\sqrt{2}\log(2-\sqrt{2})+3\sqrt{2}\log(2+\sqrt{2})\right),
$$
and
$$
I_\infty=-\frac{5}{6}+\frac{4}{3}\log2.
$$

Comment: What meaning do you give to $\log(x+y)$ when $x+y<0$?

Comment: Corrected, thanks!

Comment: The integrand is $\frac{dF}{dx} - \frac{dF}{dy}$ for $F(x, y) = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{2} \log(x+y)$, so Green's theorem if you can parametrise the boundary of $Q_p$?

Comment: thanks for the idea but I don't see how to compute the integral on the boundary of $Q_p$.